# Python list comprehension conditional filter syntax

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have list of tuples.  Some tuples have to be excluded from the list based on their item values.  An example of the list with 2 tuples is below:

```
orig_list = [('mydomain', '20150726', 'e-buyeasy.com', 'www.ujizlhekw.e', '1', 
'1', '1', '1', '100.0', '0.0'), 
('myotherdomain', '20150726', 'floating-share-buttons.com', '', '26',
'26', '26', '26', '100.0', '0.0')]
```

I created a function that uses regex matching of two tuple items against other 'lookup' lists.  The function returns True or False depending on matching against the lookup lists.

```
def tupMatch(tup):
    sourceReg="semalt.*","anticrawler.*","best-seo-offer.*","best-seo-solution.*","buttons-for-website.*","buttons-for-your-website.*","7makemoneyonline.*","-musicas*-gratis.*","kambasoft.*","savetubevideo.*","ranksonic.*","medispainstitute.*","offers.bycontext.*","100dollars-seo.*","sitevaluation.*","dailyrank.*","videos-for-your-business.*","videos-for-your-business.*","success-seo.*","4webmasters.*","get-free-traffic-now.*","free-social-buttons.*","trafficmonetizer.*","traffic2money.*","floating-share-buttons.*"

    hostnameReg="mydomain.*","myotherdomain.*"

    sourceReg2 = "(" + ")|(".join(sourceReg) + ")"
    hostnameReg2 = "(" + ")|(".join(hostnameReg) + ")"

    sourceMatch = re.match(sourceReg2, tup[2].lower())
    hostMatch = re.match(hostnameReg2, tup[3].lower())

    if (not sourceMatch) and (hostMatch):
        True
    else:
        False
    return
```

I have a list comprehension that filters the original list depending on the function result.

```
filtered_list = [tup for tup in orig_list if tupMatch(tup)]
```

However this is not actually filtering the list. I am expecting that 'tupMatch(tup)' will return either True or False and the list comprehension will have only tuples that are True.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following lines do not `return` (without `return` keywords); The function implicitly return `None`; which is considered false value.

```
if (not sourceMatch) and (hostMatch):
    True
else:
    False
```

Change the lines as following:

```
if (not sourceMatch) and (hostMatch):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

or more shortly:

```
return (not sourceMatch) and (hostMatch)   # OR  return bool(...)
```